# convert json from multiple parent id to single parent in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I have problem, I want to convert multiple parentId JSON to single parentId JSON
here is mutiple parent json example which I will provide to my js function.

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "first_name",
    "label": "First Name",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your First Name",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": "",
    "isPost": true
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "ready_to_provide_email_address",
    "label": "Ready to Provide Email Address",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your Phone Number",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "radio",
    "options": [{
        "label": "Yes",
        "name": "ready_to_provide_email",
        "value": "Yes",
        "id": "5"
      },
      {
        "label": "No",
        "name": "ready_to_provide_email",
        "value": "No",
        "id": "6"
      }
    ],
    "parentId": "",
    "isPost": false
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "email",
    "label": "Email",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your Email",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": ["5", "6"],
    "isPost": true
  }
]
```

And this is single parent json which I want in output.

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "first_name",
    "label": "First Name",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your First Name",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": "",
    "isPost": true
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "ready_to_provide_email_address",
    "label": "Ready to Provide Email Address",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your Phone Number",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "radio",
    "options": [{
        "label": "Yes",
        "name": "ready_to_provide_email",
        "value": "Yes",
        "id": "5"
      },
      {
        "label": "No",
        "name": "ready_to_provide_email",
        "value": "No",
        "id": "6"
      }
    ],
    "parentId": "",
    "isPost": false
  }, {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "email",
    "label": "Email",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your Email",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": "5",
    "isPost": true
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "email",
    "label": "Email",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your Email",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": "6",
    "isPost": true
  }
]
```

Note: object.option.id is the parent id of element in my case. Please help me. Thanks you so much in advance.

Comment: How do you want to generate a new `id` from the `parentId`?

Comment: new id can be any unique number like primary key

Comment: Try using `Array.flatMap()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: when i did i got wrong array can you please help i will be really thanksfull

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = input.map(a => a.id);
        var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, result);
        var newArr = [];
        for (var i in input) {
            var first = true;
            let objCopy = Object.assign({}, input[i].parentId);
            input[i]=Object.assign(input[i],{"initObjectPos":i});
            if(input[i].parentId.length == 0){
                input[i].parentId="";
            }
            for (var x in objCopy) {
                var y = input[i];

                if (!first) {
                    y = Object.assign({}, y);
                    max_of_array++;
                    y.id = max_of_array.toString();
                    newArr.push(y);
                }
                y.parentId = objCopy[x];
                first = false;
            }
        }
        var output = input.concat(newArr);
        return output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "first_name",
    "label": "First Name",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your First Name",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": "",
    "isPost": true
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "ready_to_provide_email_address",
    "label": "Ready to Provide Email Address",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your Phone Number",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "radio",
    "options": [{
        "label": "Yes",
        "name": "ready_to_provide_email",
        "value": "Yes",
        "id": "5"
      },
      {
        "label": "No",
        "name": "ready_to_provide_email",
        "value": "No",
        "id": "6"
      }
    ],
    "parentId": "",
    "isPost": false
  },
  {
    "id": "7",
    "name": "email",
    "label": "Email",
    "placeholder": "Enter Your Email",
    "required": "yes",
    "inputType": "text",
    "options": [],
    "parentId": ["5", "6"],
    "isPost": true
  }
];

let result = input.map(a => a.id);
var max_of_array = Math.max.apply(Math, result);
var newArr = [];

for (var i in input) {
  var first = true;
  let objCopy = Object.assign({}, input[i].parentId);
  for (var x in objCopy) {
    var y = input[i];
    if (!first) {
      y = Object.assign({}, y);
      max_of_array++;
      y.id = max_of_array.toString();
      newArr.push(y);
    }
    y.parentId = objCopy[x];
    first = false;
  }
}

var output = input.concat(newArr);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: please test you function on this json https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.1151a76cd22d413ea9f7c47004e0c00b so you will get id 10 two times which is my issue 
all object should have unique id 
Thanks

Comment: I've updated my solution and couldn't see any duplicate `id` properties when run against the new JSON provided.

Comment: yes when i copy new code duplication remove what did you change sir
also can i have you watsapp or facebook for any more issue i will glad if you give me 
Thanks much for you help

Comment: I think the main change I made was ensuring that the new `ID` properties were strings instead of numbers. Please accept the solution if it worked.

Comment: To accept an answer, click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thanks.